# Upload and display .NET source code on my website

Tags: javascript, c#, api, github

So what I want is to upload my C# projects onto my website, which I can, and then make my website show the code of my projects very nicely and smooth.

The best example you can compare this with is GitHub projects. For example: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp . It would be nice to support multiple langauges but C# is my main one. I don't want mine on GitHub but just on my website.

Any help on finding a API for this or the nessecary source code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may have seen http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ which shows code for .Net Framework.

This is done using https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/SourceBrowser. Try this and you should be able to create and host your own static HTML website to browse your C#/VB/MSBuild/TypeScript source code.

You can find more details on Channel 9 - https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/A-modern-means-to-make-your-source-browsable-online